# SymProxy not going to microsoft symbol server to find symbols

Tags: debugging, symbols, symstore

This is a repost of similar questions, but they are more than a decade old and the links to the suggestions are dead.

I'm trying to set up microsoft symproxy so I can access the debug symbols on a computer that doesn't have internet access.

I've set up symproxy as described in the microsoft pages for IIS on a Windows 10 box (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symproxy).  If I tried to read a symbol file, the clients report "not found".

In the event log, I can see 2 admin messages; ISAPI Filter started, and SymProxy Configuration Information, showing the symbol path for my proxy set to http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

In the event log "operational" section, there is a message saying "ISAPI URL Map Request - Cache Miss".

So it appears everything is set up correctly, just not the bit that forwards requests to the microsoft symbol server.

One very old post suggests turning up the logging level, but they don't say how to do that.

Any ideas?